# Django Dajax jQuery basic settings

Tags: jquery, django, dajaxice

Maybe it is so trivial but I simply can't get Dajax to work with jQuery. Everything works as expected with prototype but how to setup dajax to work with jquery? I'm use dajaxexamples and there is everything setup for prototype.

in head:

```
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>

    // Load Prototype
    google.load("prototype", "1.6.0.3");
    //google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    //google.load("mootools", "1.2.1");
    //google.load("dojo", "1.3.1");

    /**
    Callback test
    **/

    function my_callback(data){
       alert(data+' received from server');
    }

    </script>
```

in body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
/* Copyright (c) 2009-2010, Benito Jorge Bastida :: For further information check COPYING */
var Dajax = Class.create();
Dajax.prototype = {
    initialize: function(){},
    process: function(data)
    {
        if(data==Dajaxice.EXCEPTION){
            alert('Something went wrong, please reload the page.');
        }
        else{
            data.each(function(elem){
            switch(elem.cmd)
            {
                case 'alert':
                    alert(elem.val)
                break;

                case 'data':
                    eval( elem.fun+"(elem.val);" );
                break;

                case 'as':
                    $$(elem.id).each(function(e){e[elem.prop] = elem.val;});
                break;

                case 'addcc':
                    elem.val.each(function(cssclass){
                        $$(elem.id).each(function(e){ e.addClassName(cssclass);});
                    });
                break;

                case 'remcc':
                    elem.val.each(function(cssclass){
                        $$(elem.id).each(function(e){ e.removeClassName(cssclass);});
                    });
                break;

                case 'ap':
                    $$(elem.id).each(function(e){ e[elem.prop] += elem.val;});
                break;

                case 'pp':
                    $$(elem.id).each(function(e){ e[elem.prop] = elem.val + e[elem.prop];});
                break;

                case 'clr':
                    $$(elem.id).each(function(e){e[elem.prop] = "";});
                break;

                case 'red':
                    window.setTimeout('window.location="'+elem.url+'";',elem.delay);
                break;

                case 'js':
                    eval(elem.val);
                break;

                case 'rm':
                    $$(elem.id).each(function(e){e.remove();});
                break;

                default:
                    alert('Unknown action!');
                }
             });
        }
    }
};

Dajax = new Dajax();
</script>
```

What I was try is to uncomment `google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");` line and change initialize function `Dajax.prototype = {` to `Dajax.jquery = {` but it doesnt work at all.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still trying to get this to work: instead of tweaking the `Dajax.prototype = {` code manually like this, try just loading the Dajax-supplied `.js` file according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki/installation) (see the section "Include Dajax in your <head>").